# Invariant Violation:_default(...):nothing was returned from render

Tags: react-native

> Showing error My code-

```
export default()=>{
<AuthProvider>
<App/>
</AuthProvider>
};
```

I expect the output of my sign Up screen

Answer (score 2):

> Its Working For me

To add return statement with () brackets.

```
export default ()=>{
return(
<AuthProvider>
<App />
</AuthProvider>
)
};
```